# Crystal Reports XI running totals in a crosstab shown as percentage

Tags: formula, crosstab, crystal-reports-xi, cumulative-sum, summarize

I have created a crosstab with 2 separate Running Totals in my summarized fields.
I need to show these running totals as a percentage of another summarized field.

I need to add (#RTotal0 / Count of Gf.Gf_IDKEY) as a summarized field shown as a percentage.
Below that (#RTotal1 / Count of Gf.Gf_IDKEY) as a summarized field shown as a percentage.

Is there any way to do this?

[Crosstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvQ4H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think that CrossTab flexibility is very limited in this kind of modification. If I were you I would try to make the needed calculation inside Command SQL. 
You could create one more column in your query with the following percentage:

```
{your_field}/(Count of Gf.Gf_IDKEY)
```

and use this column inside a new running total, especially only for use inside your CrossTab